# How to pass postman parameters for [From body] List<int> toolId

Tags: postman-testcase

I need to test post method but how to send postman parameters for [From body] List toolId , I need to check the method but using list with formbody I am not able to send the response

Answer (score 0):

as the grammar edits of your question haven't been authorised, I'm guessing you are trying to send mock html form data, to an api, via post.

If you've the correct url in your postman request and the verb is set to post, then all you need to do is click 'body' from the menu underneath, select 'raw' and from the blue drop down on the right, select json.
Then add your list in json in the field below:

```
[
 {1}, {2}, {2147483647}, {7}
]
```

Swap the numbers I've provided with your real list of integers.

Comment: I want to check the post method in postman and the method is like public ActionResult copytool ([From body] List<int> toolId) ....     For this how to send body in postman because from postman the Id was not passed to the method

Comment: @Ayaan, sorry, I understand if English is not your first language but I am having trouble properly understanding your problem.